# Find the equation of the plane with line drawn perpendicular to the planes

Tags: analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

$PA$ and $PB$ are drawn perpendicular from $P(α, β, γ)$ to the coordinate planes $x = 0$ and $y = 0$. Show that the equation of the plane OAB is $$\frac{x}α+\frac{y}β-\frac{z}γ=0$$

Comment: If you edit the question to show what you tried you're more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close. Please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You could answer the question as posed by showing that the three points are not colinear and that they all satisfy the equation, but I suppose that whoever gave you this assignment wanted you to derive it.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:

$OA(0, β, γ)$ and $OB(α, 0, γ)$

thus a normal vector is given by the **cross product**

$$\vec n=OA\times OB=(βγ,αγ,-βα)$$

Thus the **plane equation** is:

$$βγx+αγy-βαz=0\iff \frac{x}α+\frac{y}β-\frac{z}γ=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Working in homogeneous coordinates, we have $O=[0:0:0:1]$, $A=[0:\beta:\gamma:1]$ and $B=[\alpha:0:\gamma:1]$. The plane through these three points is a homogeneous vector $\mathbf\pi$ such that $O^T\mathbf\pi=A^T\mathbf\pi=B^T\mathbf\pi=0$, i.e.,  the null vector of the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}B^T \\ A^T \\ O^T\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\alpha&0&\gamma&1 \\ 0&\beta&\gamma&1 \\ 0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ The three points can be taken in any order when forming this matrix, but this one is convenient because the matrix is then already in echelon form. Its null vector can be found by inspection: $$\left[\frac\gamma\alpha:\frac\gamma\beta:-1:0\right] = \left[\frac1\alpha:\frac1\beta:-\frac1\gamma:0\right],$$ which corresponds to the equation $\frac x\alpha+\frac y\beta-\frac z\gamma=0$. We of course require that none of $\alpha$, $\beta$ or $\gamma$ vanish.